# jsOAuth PhoneGap and Android

Tags: android, twitter, cordova, jsoauth

I searched SE's archives, google, directly ripped [this](https://gist.github.com/funkatron/979955) off and ran it and I've been on it for like 6 hours now.
Based on the link above (jsOAuth Library) I wrote my code and when I run it on my android, the inAppBrowser (correctly) redirects me to the twitter page where I'm supposed to get my pin. But instead of the pin, it shows "there is no request token for this page... " error.

I even deleted and registered a new app under a different name and got a new pair of Consumer key/secret. But that too did not budge.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792607/retrieving-access-token-from-twitter-oauth-api-with-jsoauth) could be a possible solution but even the Boilerplate example is not working. I guess I'm not getting my request token. Any help?

Comment: Same here. Seems to work on some phones (Samsung Galaxy ACE), but not others (S3 Mini).  When running in a browser on my PC I get the same message, and in the console: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token 405 (Method Not Allowed) jsOAuth-1.3.6.min.js:1
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.92:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Suggest you run "adb logcat -d > log.txt" on you PC while connected via USB to your phone.  This will give any PhoneGap/Cordova errors and console output.